# Remove slivers from merged polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, polygon-creation, slivers

I am creating a single polygon by merging different polygons in ArcMap. When I merge them, slivers are created. So I have to delete those slivers manually. I don't have a license for ArcInfo so tools like Eliminate and others are not working.

Are there any other options for removing slivers all at once in ArcMap?

I am working on ArcGIS 10.

[image: Example of sliver]

Comment: Some manual methods are better than others. On a simple situation like the examples you gave, I would go into edit vertices mode and then use the delete vertices tool to draw large polygons (avoiding the edges to be retained) to delete all the vertices within.  Alternately you can open the sketch properties box in edit vertices mode, hold the shift key and click on the first and last parts headings to select them all, then holding the Ctrl key click on those parts you don't want to delete to unselect them.  Then right click and delete.

Answer (score 10):

I think the Integrate tool from the Data Management toolbox should solve this - you can set a tolerance and it will align and remove any slivers from two polygons. [ArcGIS Integrate tool help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000002s000000)

Comment: Integrate tool does work in removing the slivers but then if I have a sliver very near to the boundary vertices or the boundary vertices itself are too close then the shape of polygon is disturbed. At that point Integrate tool will not work.

Answer (score 1):

There are many [threads](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=sliver%20polygons) on GIS Stack exchange about sliver polygons, have you looked at any of them?

Here is another approach which is partially manual and assumes your task is relatively small but does give you the ultimate decision of what is merge into what:

1. Go into edit mode.
2. Select a large polygon you want to merge slivers into.
3. Run select by location and select within the layer for polygons sharing a boundary. This will select all polygons touching your large polygon.
4. Then run a select by attribute selecting from the selection small polygons by their area.
5. Do a quick visual check on if they are sensible and then re-select the large polygon
6. On the Editor toolbar select Editor > Merge.

Comment: There is no problem in selecting the slivers as the large polygon and the slivers are a single entity.

What I need to do is eliminate those slivers from large polygon i.e. removing some part from one entity itself

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot suggest me the following approach:

- firstly, convert your polygon to lines (Feature to line);
- calculate length of lines;
- discard the "short" lines, i.e. lines whose length is less than a limit value;
- then, convert the lines to polygon (Feature to polygon);
- finally, erase the (four) holes manually.

Answer (score 0):

I usually just start editing. I then select the polygon and right click on it to edit the vertices. Once the vertices are showing, I use the delete vertices on the vertice toolbar.  I then draw a box around the vertices that are in the center of my polygon and hit enter.  This deletes the vertices of each sliver.  Once all the vertices are deleted, I save my edits.